# How to get Slack app name by client_id

Tags: slack-api, slack

I need to build an url that refers to a Slack app.

For example, 
I have an url https://slack.com/oauth/pick_reflow?scope=commands&client_id=21113332291.21116743655 and I need to convert it to something like https://slack.com/apps/A0XG4JWM8-drum-meetings

Is there any way to convert `client_id=21113332291.21116743655` to `A0XG4JWM8-drum-meetings`?